# get an "count not be supported" exception

Tags: windows-phone

I m developing an windows phone 7 app, i want to auto increment a database value that was created using code first technique.
I tried a following logic to get this done but its resulting in an exception "Method count not supported"

```
var c = new AccountEntryModel();
Expense exp = new Expense();
if (c.Expenses.Count() == 0)
exp.ExpenseId = 1;
else
exp.ExpenseId = c.Expenses.Max<Expense>(b => b.ExpenseId) + 1;
ExpenseIdTextBox.Text = exp.ExpenseId.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked fine in Windows Phone 7.1

Here is what I tried:

```
var c = new AccountEntryModel();
Expense exp = new Expense();
if (c.Expenses.Count() == 0)
   exp.ExpenseId = 1;
else
   exp.ExpenseId = c.Expenses.Max<Expense>(b => b.ExpenseId) + 1;
```

And here are the classes I created on my assumptions from your code above:

```
public class Expense
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set;}
}

public class AccountEntryModel
{
    public AccountEntryModel()
    {
        Expenses = new List<Expense>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Expenses.Add(new Expense { ExpenseId = i });
        }

    }
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set;}
}
```